# On Behalf of flow for applications without signed in users

Tags: c#, azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

We have a Azure AD secured web api which calls a backend azure service. It basically acts as a middle tier. This web api can be called by client applications with/without signed in users. We needed the web api to call azure service on behalf of clients. We implemented this for signed in users scenario based on
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow.

Now, we want to implement it for "without signed in users" scenario. We want to call azure service on behalf of calling client application. My understanding from reading the above blog is that on-behalf-of flow is not supported for applications without signed in users. Am I understanding it correctly ? Is there a way to achieve it ?

Comment: `want to call azure service on behalf of calling client application`, then what is the `azure service`? any flow provided by azure ad requires the api permission, the service decides if it's supported and how to access.

Comment: It's a azure data explorer cluster. Currently the web api executes query on it through it's own client. We want to execute the queries based on the credentials of the calling application. Web api is the middle tier here.

Comment: Then it should be client credential flow here as another contributor said in his answer but it seems he deleted his reply. You have difficulty to achieve that flow in your code?